# making a loader with svg/gif while synchronous ajax is running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Sup guys, I got an issue about the ajax.

If I'm right, using ajax in synchronous way(async = false),
browser will be locked out while ajax is running.
So I timeouted the ajax like 1ms to show the loader first but here is the thing. My loader is based on svg file which is simple spinning image and even though I timeouted the ajax functions, when ajax started, whole image froze.

Is there any way to make the image move? I really need to make this work to
let the users know that something progressing.

thank you.

:) alright I edited it. I added some source code of it

javascript part:

```
function ajaxAddrInfo(result){
//console.log("결과 값");
//console.log(daum_local);
//console.log(result[0].bcode);
sigunCd = result[0].bcode.substring(0, 5);
dongCd = result[0].bcode.substring(5, 11);
bun = result[0].jibunAddress.bunji;
ji = result[0].jibunAddress.ho;
daum_local = "";

openBgOnly();
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: './assets/php/detail.php',
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    data: {
        S_CD: sigunCd,
        D_CD: dongCd,
        BUN: bun, JI: ji, FLR: fsum,
        CNT: Bcnt,LCNT:Lcnt,
        TYPE: "Building_Count"
    },
    success:function(data){
        //console.log("working?");
        var BcntRes = JSON.parse(data);
        Bcnt = BcntRes['body']['totalCount'];
        //showResult(resf);
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert("BUILDING FLOOR SEARCH ERROR");
    },

});//ajax ends.

},1);   

//표제부

setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url: './assets/php/detail.php',
    type: 'post',
    async: false,
    data: {
        S_CD: sigunCd,
        D_CD: dongCd,
        BUN: bun, JI: ji, FLR: fsum,
        CNT: Bcnt,LCNT:Lcnt,
        TYPE: "Building_Info"
    },
    success:function(data){

        closeBg();

        var res = JSON.parse(data);
        BinfoRes = res;
        var len = res['body']['totalCount'];

        if(len === 0){
            alert("건축물 데이터가 없습니다.");
        }
        else if(len === 1){
            fsum = Number(res['body']['items']['item']['grndFlrCnt']);
            fsum += Number(res['body']['items']['item']['ugrndFlrCnt']);
        }
        else{
            //console.log(res);

            fsum = Number(res['body']['items']['item']['grndFlrCnt']);
            fsum += Number(res['body']['items']['item']['ugrndFlrCnt']);
            //console.log(fsum);
        }
        //showResult(res);

        //showResult(res);  
        $.ajax({
            url: './assets/php/detail.php',
            type: 'post',
            async: false,
            data: {
                S_CD: sigunCd,
                D_CD: dongCd,
                BUN: bun, JI: ji, FLR: fsum,
                CNT: Bcnt,LCNT:Lcnt,
                TYPE: "Building_Level_Count"
            },
            success:function(data){
                //console.log("working?");
                //console.log(data);
                LcntRes = JSON.parse(data);
                Lcnt = LcntRes['body']['totalCount'];
                //console.log(Lcnt);
                //showResult(resf); 
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("BUILDING FLOOR SEARCH ERROR");
            },
            complete:function(){

            }               
        }); 


        $.ajax({
            url: './assets/php/detail.php',
            type: 'post',
            async: false,
            data: {
                S_CD: sigunCd,
                D_CD: dongCd,
                BUN: bun, JI: ji, FLR: fsum,
                CNT: Bcnt,LCNT:Lcnt,
                TYPE: "Building_Level_Info"
            },
            success:function(data){
                //console.log("working?");
                //console.log(data);
                resfloor = JSON.parse(data);

                //showResult(resf); 
            },
            error: function(error){
                alert("BUILDING FLOOR SEARCH ERROR");
            },
            complete:function(){

            }               
        }); 


        B_List(res);
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert("BUILDING SEARCH ERROR");

    },
    complete:function(){

    }               
});
},1);
//층별
//setTimeout(closeLoading(),1500);
```

}

html part :

```
<div id="loading_background" class="text-center"><p id="loading_content"><img src="./assets/img/loader.svg" class="put-img-center"><h3>로딩중...</h3></p></div>
```

Comment: Can you include some code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: ehhh sorry my code is way to long to append but the structure of that is like, function(){openLoader(); setTimeout(function(){$.ajax()... success: closeLoader(); another $.ajax(); }, 1);} and all the ajax r async : false

Comment: @hellikiam You just have to show us the ajax part...

Comment: "Synchronous ajax" === "Not the way to go". End of story.

Comment: alright I got it I added the source code

Comment: @JeremyThille sorry dude but I really need to stick on this, this is my seniors decision have no another choice

Comment: Funny... "Take a super powerful feature and remove the power from it" :) Besides, async ajax [deprecated and about to be removed](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning). You really should tell this to your ol.... your seniors.

Comment: *SYNC ajax is deprecated (typo)